# How to send email by the Facebook app

Tags: php, email, facebook-apps

I am developing a basic Facebook app that is hosted on Hostgator. 
Here is the link of my app :  https://apps.facebook.com/191327857669038/.

The app is supposed to send the completed form data to the respondent and a copy to App Admin, but the emails are not being sent.

I used the following PHP script to test whether it is sending a test email or not. I added this script to my “index.php” page, and after committing all the changes, I tested it, but it didn’t work.

```
<?php
$to = "example@gmail.com";
  $subject = "Hi!";
  $body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";
  $email = "myemail@yahoo.com" ;
if (mail($to, $subject, $body,"From: $email")) {
   echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
  } else {
   echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
  }
?>
```

How can I send email from my Facebook app effectively?

Comment: What happens if you leave off the `"From: $email"`?

Answer (score 1):

I think, for Yahoo, you need to login with your credentials and make use of their SSL port to send emails. So you need to use a better mailing system.

Try using the PHP Mailer: http://phpmailer.worxware.com/

Here's an example on using Yahoo SMTP to send email using PHP Mailer: http://faq.pctrickers.com/php-send-yahoo-email-using-smtp/

Worth reading - Yahoo SMTP/POP settings: http://help.yahoo.com/l/in/yahoo/smallbusiness/bizmail/pop/pop-33.html

Hope it helps :)

Comment: + 1. PHP Mailer is the way to go if you are sending emails with PHP.